# Weyl character formula and Harish-Chandra isomorphism

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

In the Application section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harish-Chandra_isomorphism it says

> Blockquote
>   The theorem may be used to obtain a simple algebraic proof of Weyl's character formula for finite-dimensional representations.

Does anyone have a reference for this proof?

Thanks.